# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installation failure - no internet connectivity - now what?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a 64 bit server that is not connected to the network and was updating my VS2010 with the SP1. The program is trying to download a VS10sp1_x86.msi file from the source but since no connectivity, the intall fails.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

You should download the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691#instructions) as an ISO image and burn it to disc or mount it locally. Then install from that media.

Look for the link at the bottom of the page.

[image]